# Loading a PDF in SfPdfViewerControl with default view mode

Tags: uwp, syncfusion

I'm trying to implement a PDF viewer with the *Syncfusion*'s solution, *SfPdfViewerControl*. I need to have a default state for this viewer's **ViewMode** (fit width or height), in a *Syncfusion.Windows.PdfViewer.PageViewMode*'s enum called **_defaultDisplayType**.

To do so, i'm simply doing a :

```
_pdfViewer.ViewMode = PageViewMode.FitWidth;
```

Where **_pdfViewer** is my instance of *SfPdfViewerControl*.

I'm doing it when the **_pdfViewer** trigger his **DocumentLoaded** event :

```
_pdfViewer.DocumentLoaded += _pdfViewer_CurrentDocumentLoaded;
```

And my method called looks like :

```
private void _pdfViewer_CurrentDocumentLoaded(object sender, DocumentLoadedEventArgs e)
    {
        _pdfViewer.ViewMode = _defaultDisplayType;
    }
```

However, even though the **ViewMode**'s property properly changes to **FitWidth**, the final result looks like this :

[image: Loaded PDF]

And when I try to change the **ViewMode**'s value manually, from a button, the viewer finally sized well :

[image: PDF viewer after changing the ViewMode's property]

Am I doing it wrong ? I assume that I should be using some kind of setter method or command but the [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfpdfviewer/concepts-and-features/working-with-magnification) doesn't seems to prove me wrong.

Comment: when/how is the `_defaultDisplayType` property initialized?

Comment: In the constructor, and the value is right (PageViewMode.FitWidth) when the DocumentLoaded event is triggered and when I change it manually.

Comment: if you delay the setting of _pdfViewer.ViewMode_ property for a 1 second, using `async` and `await Task.Delay`, what happen? It feels like the setting does not take effect if it takes place _immediately_ after the DocumentLoaded event...

Comment: It does work when I delay the setting, but I'm getting a "Attempted to divide by zero." exception when I'm navigating between my documents. 
Strange thing is that I don't get these problems when I set the value to OnePage (fit height).
I'll contact the Syncfusion's support and update this post later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reproduce the issue on our side. The fix for this issue will be included in our main release Essential Studio Volume 2 which is expected to be available by the end of April, 2017.

Best,
Navaneetha Kannan